# How to type correctly the location you get from mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the next code, and dont understand how correctly types location

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>, {location}) => {
    return {
        checkAuth: () => dispatch(checkAuth(location.pathname))
    }
}
```

I read about RouteProps but it dont work(

Comment: try {location}: {location: ILocation}

Comment: RouteComponentProps help me